# Square Root Begins with the Same Digits

Tags: number-theory

Are there any natural numbers $n$ such that $\sqrt n$, when expressed as a decimal, begins with the same string of numerals?  For example, $\sqrt {100}  = 10.00000.$ Obviously even powers of $10$ work, but what about non-trivial solutions?  What about other bases?

Comment: Same string till what length? The first digit? First two? First $n$?

Comment: $\sqrt{0}=0$, $\sqrt{121}=11$, etc.

Comment: How about $10^{2k}-1$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

Write $n=a 10^m$ where $1\le a <10$.

If $m=2k$, $\sqrt n = \sqrt a 10^k$
so we want $a \approx \sqrt a$
or $a \approx 1$.

If $m=2k+1$, $\sqrt n = \sqrt{10a}10^k$
so we want $a \approx \sqrt{10a}$
or $a \approx 10$.

However you can for cube root.
$\sqrt[3]{31.6} \approx 3.16$.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how long you want the leading string to be, consider $10^k+1$.  It starts with a $1$ followed by $k-1$ zeros.  $\left(10^k+1\right)^2=10^{2k}+2\cdot 10^k+1$ so it starts with a $1$ followed by $k-1$ zeros.  This is not quite your trivial solution and works in any base.